# Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems

In my Gemfile I have: mysql2 (0.4.4)

I got this error when launching my Rails server: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

I read and searched some threads on this website. The recommendations were to downgrade mysql2

"version 0.3.18 of mysql2 by adding this line to your gemfile:

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'"

When I did this I tried to rerun bundle install and I got this error.

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: unterminated string meets end of file. Bundler cannot continue.

#  from /Users/john-michaelnalettenalette/simple_cms/Gemfile:7
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  # Use mysql as the database for Active Record

> gem ‘mysql2’, `~> 0.3.20’ 
>    #  # Use SCSS for stylesheets
>    #  -------------------------------------------

Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please click on accept answer(the V mark on the left side of my answer) so that people know that the question is solved. And you will help me with it aswell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started a string which you didn't end at the end of this line :

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'"
```

**Change it to this:**

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
```

Comment: It is important to note that there are many mysql2 versions listed here https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2/versions
Choose the version that suits you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on rails v 4.2.10. Ubuntu 18:10
Installing mysql2 0.3.21 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
the solution suggested in the error message was:

libmysqlclient is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev'

### or 'yum install mysql-devel', and try again.

this worked!

note: I am bundling an old app which depended on mysql, which is not yet installed on my machine. installing mysql may also have solved my issue.